# how to redirect to shopping cart page by clicking proceed to checkout button in magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, api

how to redirect to shopping cart page by clicking proceed to checkout button in magento2 . And which file need to add in our custom module

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to the shopping cart by clicking on 'proceed-to-checkout button' **in the minicart** you can edit 'Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php' function 'getConfig' and edit 'checkoutUrl'

Here is the way to do it in your custom module

### 1. In your di.xml

Add a plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar">
        <plugin name="UpdateMinicartCheckoutLInk"
            type="Connector\Integration\Plugin\UpdateMinicartCheckoutLInk"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

### 2. Create the plugin file

In the folder Plugin create `UpdateMinicartCheckoutLink.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Magento\Plugin;

use Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar;

class UpdateMinicartCheckoutLink
{
    /**
     * @param Sidebar $subject
     * @param array $result
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetConfig(Sidebar $subject, array $result): array
    {
        $result['checkoutUrl'] = $subject->getShoppingCartUrl();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

### 3. Flush magento cache

```
bin/magento c:f
```